# How to autostart an app with windows phone

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

I need to autostart the app Cortana (for instance) any time I turn on my device.

Is it possible with my windows phone 8.1?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Windows Phone does not have a autostart feature. You could perhaps launch Cortana through an NFC tag.